# Fixing wget certificates

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, wget

Basically, I was testing different versions of OpenSSL, and somewhere in the process broke wget's path to certificates.

```
wget https://www.google.com
```

Results now in:

```
ERROR: cannot verify www.google.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US':
Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.google.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

Which makes me think that wget doesn't know where to look for certificates, as `ca-certificates` is installed and if I set `export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs` everything works until reboot.

How can I permanently fix this? I want to revert to the original state, where wget automatically knows where to check certificates.

I can probably set this export on boot, but what it the right place, where it originally was?

#### Edit:

On another server, I've checked and there is no `SSL_CERT_DIR` variable in the environment, yet wget works correctly. How does wget knows where to look for certificates?

Answer (score 5):

Usually, the distribution will specify this in the global `wgetrc` file. For example, Arch Linux has this in `/etc/wgetrc`:

`ca_certificate=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

So, just find where your certificates live, and pass it to wgetrc.

Comment: Hey, I change to ca_directory=/etc/ssl/certs/ and it works. Thanks! Yet, on other server everything is the same, and without extra .wgetrc file, wget works. Will research further

Comment: If you have trouble locating these files, I used `locate wgetrc` and `locate ca-certificates.crt` to confirm where both the certificate file and wgetrc file is located.

Answer (score 1):

It is set at `./configure` time by the `--openssldir` option.
wget will look for certificates in that directory.

You can find more on that here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200058/39382

Comment: Hey, I've check my other servers, and `openssl version -d` returns /usr/local/ssl/, however there is no certs folder. Actual folder is in /etc/ssl/certs, but somehow wget works. I'm definitely missing something

Comment: It makes sense, and should work, but even after I added symlinks from `etc/ssl/certs` to `/usr/local/ssl` (which is my openssldir), wget refuse to work.

Comment: Hey, you've right about openssldir, the problem is that wget looks in `usr/lib/ssl/certs`, instead of `/usr/local/ssl`. Temporarily added symlink, but perhaps it's better to recompile and keep everything in '/usr'. I guess other packages can also break in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, you can point `wget` to the `cert.pem` file with this:

```
wget --ca-certificate=/etc/ssl/cert.pem
```

or in your `.wgetrc`:

```
ca-certificate = /etc/ssl/cert.pem
```

This works on macOS 10.14; other versions with the file in the same place will should ostensibly work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an available option in linux sadly.

Answer (score 0):

This can be LetsEncrypt Root CA expire related:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181231/server-certificate-verification-failed-cafile-etc-ssl-certs-ca-certificates-c/69562796#69562796

Just

- update openssl version>1.0.2
- disable DST_Root_CA_X3 in /etc/ca-certificates.conf
- install new X1 root CA

Answer (score 0):

The solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445609/20113) fixed my issue with this.

Basically, you use your package manager to install/upgrade your ca-certificates.

```
sudo yum install ca-certificate
```